# fontawesome com vuetify

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify

estou inciando um projeto VUEJ+vuetify. 
Implementei o pacote do fontawesome para utilizar dos icones free que disponibilizaram.
entretanto, todos os componentes renderizados no navegador que utilizam algum icone, estou tendo o seguinte erro no console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A configuração foi feita da seguinte maneira.

Critei um arquivo.js denominado **'fontawesome.js'** onde importo os icones que irei utilizar.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { faHome, faUser, faIdCard, faSignOutAlt, faSignInAlt, faSync, faBan, faLayerGroup, faServer, faUsers, faChartLine } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

library.add(faHome, faUser, faIdCard, faSignOutAlt, faSignInAlt, faSync, faBan, faLayerGroup, faServer, faUsers, faChartLine);

export default {
    home: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'home'] } },
    user: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'user'] } },
    idCard: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'id-card'] } },
    signOutAlt: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'sign-out-alt'] } },
    signInAlt: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'sign-in-alt'] } },
    sync: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'sync'] } },
    ban: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'ban'] } },
    layerGroup: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'layer-group'] } },
    server: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'server'] } },
    users: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'users'] } },
    chartLine: { component: FontAwesomeIcon, props: { icon: ['fas', 'chart-line'] } },
};
```

Dentro do meu **vuetify.js** importo o fontawesome, junto com algumas configurações de temas.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors';
import icons from './fontawesome';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: colors.purple.darken1, // #E53935
                secondary: colors.blue.lighten1, // #FFCDD2
                accent: colors.indigo.base, // #3F51B5
                error: colors.red.darken1,
                sucess: colors.green.lighten2,
            },
        },
    },
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'faSvg',
        values: icons,
    },
});
```

E para a utilização do incone faço da seguinte maneira.

```
             <v-btn
                small
                dark
                text
                @click="logout"
            >
                <v-icon v-text="'$vuetify.icons.signInAlt'" />
                <span class="ml-2">Sair</span>
            </v-btn>
```

Os icones aparecem normalmente nas páginas, porem a quantidade de erros no console é enorme. Alguem sabe me dizer como resolver esse problema ? Tentei algumas coisas que vi na net a respeito, porem nada surtiu efeito...
att.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui resolver da seguinte maneira.
Isso ocorre porque existe um problema de compatibilidade com as ultimas versoes do vue e vuetify.
Então fiz o downgrade do vue e vue-template-compiler para a versão 2.6.10, pois estava utilizando a '11'

```
npm install vue@2.6.10 vue-template-compiler@2.6.10
```

Caso alguem passe pelo mesmo problema...